# Creating new column by row values in two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am trying to make a new column based on combination of values in two columns

the original df I have is below

```
|  id | code_1   | code_2  |
| --- | -------- |  -----  |
| A0  | 001      |  X1     |
| A1  | 001      |  X2     |
| A2  | 001      |  x3     |
| A3  | 001      |  x4     |
| A4  | 002      |  X1     |
| A5  | 002      |  X2     |
```

regardless of the id in first column, I am only considering the combination of second and third column which are 'code_1' and 'code_2'

If the 'code_1' is 001 and 'code_2' is x1, x2 and x3, I want to create new column and give **Y1**

If the 'code_1' is 001 and 'code_2' is x4, then I want to give **Y2**

If the 'code_2' is 002 and 'code_2' is x1 and x2, then I want to give **Z1**

So, the final output for this table would look like below:

```
|  id | code_1   | code_2  |  new_code  |
| --- | -------- |  -----  |  --------  |
| A0  | 001      |  X1     |  Y1        |
| A1  | 001      |  X2     |  Y1        |
| A2  | 001      |  x3     |  Y1        |
| A3  | 001      |  x4     |  Y2        |
| A4  | 002      |  X1     |  Z1        |
| A5  | 002      |  X2     |  Z1        |
```

Thank you

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with chain conditions by `&` for bitwise `AND` and tested by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
m1 = df['code_1'].eq('001') & df['code_2'].isin(['x1', 'x2', 'x3'])
m2 = df['code_1'].eq('001') & df['code_2'].eq('x4')
m2 = df['code_1'].eq('002') & df['code_2'].eq(['x1', 'x2'])

df['new_code'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], ['Y1','Y2','Z1'])
```